# How to build DCMTK library to use in iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, cmake, xcodebuild

I'm newbie to iPhone programming.I want to use [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) library in my iPhone project to display DICOM image but I don't know how.

I search google to use DCMTK on iPhone project.They tell me use CMake to configure and build on XCode. I have already successfully used CCmake to compile dcmtk3.6 but not build it in ios environment on XCode.It have 69 error of dcmprscp about Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error.

Have any idea,Thank you for answer. :)

ps.sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

We can use DCMTK on iOS. The follow link will help someone who looks for information about this.

http://www.cppblog.com/kesalin/archive/2011/11/10/dcmtk_ios.html

That post is written in Chinese with many screenshots, we still can get enough information to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely NOT a cmake issue, but rather an issue with trying to use DCMTK for iphone.

Answer (score 0):

The "dcmprscp" module appears to be a command line tool, which I wouldn't expect to work under iOS.  Start with building the DCMTK libraries under iOS & skip building the command line tools completely.